# VBA to escape to next set of code if no data were found

Tags: excel, vba

what I want to do is that I have extract data from SAP presented in sheet 1

Firstly: I filter column A for a cell that contains the text "A11", column C for "2789001", and Column B for "ADR" then I copy the filtered data to a new cell, and so on,

I need to insert a line in my macro where it says if you can't find the filtered data just move on to the next set of code and keep filtering sheet 1 but I have so many lines and a lot of data to be filtered and I can't find a VBA code where it can deal with all these filters.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Al1"
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="2789001"
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="ADR"

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
If Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False Then
MsgBox "There are no filtered rows"
Exit Sub
End If
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
ws.Name = "AL1 - ADR"
 rng.Copy Range("A1")


    

End With

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="ADR"
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1542001"
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="AL1"

'Set variables
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim iSourceLastRow As Long
Dim iTargetLastRow As Long
'Set variables for source and destination sheets
Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsTarget = Worksheets("ADR - AL1")
'Find last used row in the source sheet based on data in column B
iSourceLastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Find first blank row in the destination sheet based on data in column B
'Offset property is to move the copied data 1 row down
iTargetLastRow = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(5).Row
'Copy data from the source and Paste in the destination

Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Offset(0)
    

rng.Copy wsTarget.Range("A" & iTargetLastRow)

Columns("L:M").Insert
 Range("L1").Value = "Reconcile"
 Range("M1").Value = "Yes"
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
  
  Set rng1 = Columns("K").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).Areas(1)
  Set rng2 = Columns("K").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).Areas(2)
  Intersect(rng1.EntireRow, Columns("A:Y")).Sort Key1:=rng1, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
  Intersect(rng2.EntireRow, Columns("A:Y")).Sort Key1:=rng2, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
  rng1.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).Formula = Array( _
    "=INT(ABS(K2))&"" - ""&COUNTIF(L$1:L1,INT(ABS(K2))&"" -*"")+1", _
    "=IF(COUNTIF($L$2:$L$" & rng2.Row + rng2.Rows.Count - 1 & ",L2)=2,""x"","""")")
 rng2.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).Formula = Array( _
    Replace(Replace("=INT(ABS(K#))&"" - ""&COUNTIF(L$%:L%,INT(ABS(K#))&"" -*"")+1", "#", rng2.Row), "%", rng2.Row - 1), _
    "=IF(COUNTIF($L$2:$L$" & rng2.Row + rng2.Rows.Count - 1 & ",L" & rng2.Row & ")=2,""x"","""")")
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

    
' Color the filtered numbers that matches
'Create variables to hold the number of rows for the tabular data
Dim RRow As Long, N As Long
'Capture the number of rows within the tabular data range
RRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Iterate through all the rows in the tabular data range
For N = 1 To RRow
    'Use a Select Case statement to evaluate the formatting based on column 2
    Select Case ActiveSheet.Cells(N, 13).Value
        'Turn the interior color to blue
        Case "x"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(N, 11).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 255, 204)
        'Turn the interior color to red
    End Select
        Select Case ActiveSheet.Cells(N, 13).Value
        Case "x"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(N, 12).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 255, 204)

    End Select

Next N




With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="ESL"
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="2780001"
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="ASL"



If Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False Then
MsgBox "There are no filtered rows"
Exit Sub
End If
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range
Set ws = Worksheets.Add
ws.Name = "ESL - ASL"
 rng.Copy Range("A1")
 

End With
    
  Next ws

End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: No one is going to read through almost 600 lines of code here. That said break it down into individual subroutines and a main sub that calls them all and leave in the `exit sub`s

Comment: ^^^Alternatively, using an `Else` statement or maybe `Select Case`? Properly indenting your code would also greatly increase readability

Comment: @Warcupine Sorry about that, just updated my post, basically i filter set of data, move to a new sheet and reconcile it, i end up with around 7 new sheets of data. so how can i make it move to the next block of code if no filtered data were found

Comment: You can use `GoTo`